Which verb number does zero take?
(Creating spreadsheets can lead you into unexpected directions.) As many are aware of, the number zero itself, is a fairly recent invention, but words for it of course do and did exist in Latin; Cassell (24th edition, 1946) lists nihil for ‘zero’, and then there is nūllus < nē ūllus (Latinsk ordbok, Cappelen, 1998). But which number does it take?
Nils Sjöstrand (Ny latinsk grammatik, Gleerup, Malmö, 1960) seems to only discuss nūllus’s usage as a negation. Latinsk ordbok presents some predicate examples:

mortuī nūllī sunt (does not exist)
eās lēge nūllās putās (you do not consider as laws)
sine hīs studiīs vītam nūllam esse putāmus ([without these endeavours] there [is] no real life)
quam nūllae sunt vīrēs meae! (how weak are my powers!)
nūllōs jūdicēs habēmus (we have veritable fools for judges)
patre nūllō nātus (unknown)
nūllus es (you’re a goner)

But none of these examples seem to consider zero a subject in and of itself. I assume this would not be done in neither classical or mediaeval latin, but modern Latin? In Norwegian, a number can be the subject of a sentence:

Den femmeren der er grønn: Ille quīnque viridis est.

How would one refer to the number 0, i.e.  which number would its verb take? Some angles of attack might be:

Examples of this in Neo-Latin and Modern Latin writers
Examples of this from ancient authors


The concept of 0 wasn't widely used in antiquity (and thought to be non-existent until the Archimedes palimpsest), so you'll not get ancient examples. Unless you want ancient examples of nihil? But "zero" and "nothing" are not exactly synonymous.

I'm assuming you mean zero of something, not zero as a digit? Compare how we say "two apples are" but "the number two is".

Also see this related question.

@cmw That is what I suggested by my opening remark: ‘the number zero itself, is a fairly recent invention’. Draconis: Yes, zero as something. cmw: I searched, but obviously used the wrong search terms. I have flagged this question to be closed as a duplicate. Thanks!
